# Slack message "link button" not showing when URL contains underscore

Tags: url, slack

I searched high and low but couldn't find a solution for this...
I'm designing a basic slack message with **link buttons** and found that the button **will not show** in the message when the **host contains an 'underscore'**...

You can try below example here: https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder

`{
    "text": "some text here...",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "title": "TITLE",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "text": "Link button",
                    "url": "https://www.some-site.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}`

When you change `www.some-site.com` to `www.some_site.com`, the button disappears ...

Any suggestions on how to format the url so that the button shows up? According to the documentation, only the `&`, `<` and `>` characters need to be escaped, correct? I also tried encoding the URL, that didn't help either ... help?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here...
Did you find a solution? Nothing I do is working.

So weird slack did this!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid response from Slack, since `www.some_site.com` is not a valid URL.

You can not use underscores in hostnames, where hostname in your example is `some-site`. You can however use underscores in the label of a URL, so e.g. `www_super.some-site.com` should work.

Sources:
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names
- http://domainkeys.sourceforge.net/underscore.html

Comment: thx for the response - i tried your example `www_super.some-site.com` in the slack message-builder and it didn't work either ... i think it simply doesn't like underscores anywhere in the fqdn ... unfortunately, the internal server that i'm trying to link to has a hostname like this: `some_thing_interesting.int.company.com` ... :(

Comment: sorry to hear that it does not work either. Alternatively, you could consider a "bridge" endpoint, which routes all requests between Slack and the internal server with the weird host name